# Which library should I link to use DirectX Media Object Wrapper Filter?

Tags: visual-c++, dependencies, directx, linker-errors

I extract a very little snippet of code of my C++ application:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Dshow.h"
#include "dmodshow.h"

int main()
{
    IBaseFilter         *audioWrapper = NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DMOWrapperFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&(audioWrapper));

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I want to create an instance of a [DMO Wrapper Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/dmo-wrapper-filter). The application compiles well but when I link, I get:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_DMOWrapperFilter

However, I correctly add `Strmiids.lib` and `Quartz.lib` in my dependencies as said in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/setting-up-the-build-environment) but it still doesn't work.

I know the SDK is correctly installed on my system because I can compile another application who use DirectShow but I didn't find the dependency is need in this particular case.

So, has anyone an idea of which library I should use to compile my application?

Comment: All those things are part of the Windows SDK. You don't need the legacy DirectX SDK at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the DMO GUIDs are exported by the `dmoguids.lib` library and `CLSID_DMOWrapperFilter` is part of it (even if it is defined in `dmodshow.h`).

Indeed, the documentation page of the [DMO GUIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/dmo-guids) says:

> These GUIDs are defined in the header file Dmoreg.h and exported by the Dmoguids.lib library.